# How are regular permissions and ACL permissions linked?

Tags: linux, acl

I'm using Ubuntu and I would like to know if the regular permissions and the user,group,other permissions found in an ACL (when displayed) are actually two different sets of permissions or is it actually one set of permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The ACL system knows these entries:

- ACL_USER_OBJ
  The ACL_USER_OBJ entry denotes access rights for the file owner.
- ACL_GROUP_OBJ
  The ACL_GROUP_OBJ entry denotes access rights for the file group.
- ACL_OTHER
  The ACL_OTHER entry denotes access rights for processes that do not match any other entry in the ACL.

These are the old entries. The new ones are:

- ACL_USER
  ACL_USER entries denote access rights for users identified by the entry's qualifier.
- ACL_GROUP
  ACL_GROUP entries denote access rights for groups identified by the entry's qualifier.
- ACL_MASK
  The ACL_MASK entry denotes the maximum access rights that can be granted by entries of type ACL_USER, ACL_GROUP_OBJ, or ACL_GROUP.

### precedence

- ACL_USER_OBJ takes precedence over ACL_USER
- ACL_USER takes precedence over ACL_GROUP_OBJ
- ACL_GROUP_OBJ takes precedence over ACL_GROUP